# Separate headphone and speaker volume

Tags: volume

Is there any way in WP to control the headphone and speaker volume separately? I'm finding the headphone volume of my 1020 quite quiet, and then when I switch back to speaker it's too loud.

Answer (score 2):

That is currently not possible. There is a [uservoice](http://windowsphone.uservoice.com/forums/101801-feature-suggestions/suggestions/4623672-different-volume-between-headphones-and-speaker) forum you could support. Microsoft does comb these suggestions to add features in upcoming releases.

Comment: Should add, this feature is already in Windows 8... given the rumours of Windows 8.1 merging with RT, we might get this feature then :)

Comment: @rikkit Looking forward to seeing which windows 8 & 8.1 features get ported to WP 8.1. There's potential for it to be a HUGE upgrade